# HTML5 Video not working only in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, html5-video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE9 HTML5 video support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913377/ie9-html5-video-support)

I am working with a client to try and get their video player working. It seems to work in everything that I can test in except IE9.  I'm using videojs (I've tried other ones and the same result).

It seems to be that it's one of 2 things. A setting on their IIS server. Or the video file isn't encoded correctly.

Here's the test page: https://vdsc.com/video-js2/demo.html

Comment: I don't think its an IIS configuration as I can hit the URL in IE9(directly to it) and it will open and play in Windows Media Player.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. Another thought is maybe because it's https videoJS doesn't like it. But i've tried using other players as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

had a similiar issue, and i had to register the mime types via .htaccess on my server (mp4 didn t work before).

.htaccess-file:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/mp4 .mov
AddType video/webm .webm
```

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure its the IIS settings; try adding these file name extensions and corresponding MIME types:
.webm  –     “video/webm”

.ogg -           “application/ogg”

.ogv -           “video/ogg”

.mp4-           “video/mp4″

.m4v -           “video/m4v”

you can read about it here: http://blog.j6consultants.com.au/2011/01/10/cross-browser-html5-video-running-under-iis-7-5/

Comment: saved by the wayback machine yet again! http://web.archive.org/web/20130212103241/http://blog.j6consultants.com.au/2011/01/10/cross-browser-html5-video-running-under-iis-7-5