# why metatag for compatibilty not working in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

```
 <title>::.ACCRMS .::</title>
    <%-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"/>--%>
    <link href="../Styles/ACACommon.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Styles/MenuStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Styles/CalendarControl.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

I HAVE TO MAKE IE8 TO WORK IN COMPATIBILTY VIEW

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519645/force-ie9-into-browser-compatibility-view

Comment: where should i place this metatag

Comment: where the meta tags go... have you looked at the similar question ? Anyway what you're trying to do is hard to achieve, and actuall that's a good thing, even if it's annoying at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tell IE 8 to show the page in compatibility view, you tell it that the page isn't built for IE 8:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

In your code you have commented out this meta tag, and have one that instead tells IE that the page *is* built for IE 8.

Comment: its not working ......I am getting mad............... i saw there is importance in position of meta tag...... can you say exactly where should i place it.....

Comment: @user2028956: It should be inside the `head` tag. Preferrably early, as it might affect how other settings are used in the rendering.