# HTML 5 Video tag not working for any browser

Tags: html, html5-video

So I used AnyConverter do convert a `.mov` to `.mpf`, `.ogv` and `.webm` formats. I then put them in a video directory and used the following code

```
 <video width="500" height="281">
    <source src="/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="/video/video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="/video/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

However, the video does not show in Sarari, Chrome or Firefox newest versions.
I'm using the HTML 5 Doctype and not sure what is happening. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Odd, I changed the path to the full url and it still did not work. Then when I pasted the url in Firefox the video played. I wonder if its something outside of the video tag...

Comment: Is it playing at all in any browser?

Comment: check server configuration of the `MIME types` as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220537/html5-video-not-working-only-in-ie9/9224952#9224952

Comment: I had this problem too. Got it sorted. I am using angular JS. I had src={{selectedVideo.url}} in the video src attribute. The url was coming from an API call. Although the right url was in the element when I inspected it it still wasn't playing. It turned out I needed to load the video player after the new src was updated. So something like: video_player_id.load(); Hope this helps.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make sure your path is correct for video files. rest of the code is fine

Add Controls Attribute on Video Tag like: 
Here is the full reference http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

```
<video width="500" height="281" controls>
    <source src="/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="/video/video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="/video/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

Comment: Good point at https://stackoverflow.com/q/21004335/1830909 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/46983622/1830909

Comment: This suggets that the controls property is required to make it work which sounds like non-sense because it is optional. `controls: If this attribute is present, the browser will offer controls to allow the user to control video playback, including volume, seeking, and pause/resume playback`

And it is because when i added the controls property it still didn't work. When I use the src attribute on the `video` element it works when I use the `source` element within the `video` element it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

Add **`controls`** attribute on video node

### Example:

```
<video width="500" height="281" controls>
   ...
   ...
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you indicated in your edit seems to point towards a mime types issue. I have summarized some common troubleshooting steps with HTML5 video playback in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329770/html5-video-not-working-in-any-browser/).

There are 3 things to check:

- make sure your video files are properly encoded for web delivery
- make sure the server where the videos are hosted is properly configured for web delivery
- make sure your others scripts on the page do not interfere with video playback

Let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your video's file name contains any spaces in between words and either remove them or replace them with a HTML space %20:

Bad:

```
/video/My Video.mp4
```

Good:

```
/video/My%20Video.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <video width="500" height="281" controls>
     <source src="/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
     <source src="/video/video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
     <source src="/video/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>

it will still render as audio because mp4 is still not fully supported.
To solve this problem, place the currently supported format at the top.
like this:

<video width="900" height="600" controls>
     <source src="/video/video.webm" type="video/webm"> 
     <source src="/video/video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
     <source src="/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```