# MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type:

Tags: html, video, html5-video, mp4

I am having an issue with an MP4 video in IE. I am getting a "MEDIA12899: AUDIO/VIDEO: Unknown MIME type:" error in IE. I am thinking it is an issue with either server that is hosting the file or the mp4 that was supplied to me. works fine in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. In IE 9, I am getting a more defined error... "Unable to get property 'pow' of undefined or null reference"

```
    <source src="http://dummyurl.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://dummyurl.com/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="http://dummyurl.com/video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
```

any thoughts or ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the answer of your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22366971/5431346

You have to render your video with H.264 codec AND move the file info to the file header for IE9 support.

Comment: thanks WDJ, am away from work right now, but will give this a try first thing in the am and will let you know

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what moving it to the header would do for it? says it will play on page load, wouldn't the error still persist regardless? I don't want it to play on page load, but only when the user clicks the play button. my code works fine as is on another site on other servers. its just when I try to apply to a different vendor supplied mp4 hosted on a different server...

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when using an old apache2 web server.  It sent the mp4 video with `Content-Type: text/plain`.  I have JS code to play the video repeatedly according to a schedule.  IE11 would play the video OK the first time, but gave this error when my JS code tried to play it again.  I guess this might be similar to your problem with the play button.  I fixed it by defining the missing MIME types in the apache2 config files:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```